# Unique way of saying fulfilling some one else's dream for them

Tags: single-word-requests

My daughter is a famous motorcyclist and has to answer hundreds of interviews.  In her interviews she says that she is fulfilling her father's "legacy".  I have always felt she is using the wrong word.

She could say she is "fulfilling her father's unfulfilled dream".

My daughter wants to use a dramatic word but I feel she is using the wrong one. "Legacy" has to do with money.

Can someone suggest a unique word?

Comment: [vicarious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vicarious) *Experienced in the imagination through the feelings **or actions** of another person*

Comment: Legacy does *not* have to do with money; I'm not sure where you got that.  Legacy refers posthumously to someone's accomplishments , the people they've touched through their actions, their work that can be continued after they're gone.

Comment: I agree she’s using the wrong word.  But legacy doesn’t have to do with money.  It’s something that is bequeathed in a will, usually used when the thing being bequeathed is an important and defining property of the deceased- something that will live on after they’re gone.  Perhaps your daughter ***is*** her father’s legacy. If she is carrying on in the footsteps of her father, doing the things he wanted to do but never got the chance, she might be fulfilling her family’s destiny.

Comment: Thank You Very Much for clearing my misunderstanding about the meaning of 'Legacy'

Comment: She's a chip off the old block?

Answer (score 2):

If she is continuing her father's success in a particular activity she may be 'continuing her father's legacy'. This conveys the meaning that her activities are a continuation of what her father had already accomplished.
She would only be able to 'fulfil' something her father was unable to accomplish (dreams, lifelong ambition, goal).

Answer (score 2):

There is in "following in her father's footsteps", as in taking on a profession the father had started on.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy simply means *"the things that someone left behind for their children or successors"*, usually when they die but sometimes when they retire.  (It sounds like the latter in your case)

If part of her fathers legacy was *"a desire to win motor cycle racing championships"*, or more simply *"a passion for racing"*, and she has won some championships (if she's done hundreds of interviews then I'm guessing she has won some), or perhaps just has that passion for racing, then she can legitimately say she is fullfilling her father's legacy: her father left her with a desire to race motorbikes, and she's doing that.

EDIT:  You say she's a famous motorcyclist, rather than a racer:  that was just my assumption as I don't know how else someone would become famous for riding a motorbike.